# SPSS compute score of 4 different binary variables for cross tabs sum

Tags: sum, spss, crosstab

I did a survey for my thesis and currently work in SPSS. The respondents had to pick in four different questions a product between two choices. Those choices I have recoded to "0" and "1" (greener option not chosen, green option chosen). The respondents were in two condition groups, were some were provided with a label indicating which is the "better" option whereas others didn't have an indication. Now I want to measure 1) to how many was a label provided & 2) how many picked the "better" option. The problem is, I can't get rid of the product level.

**This is how I have it:**

[image]

**And this is how I need it:**

[image]

As you can see, the total number are all respondents * 4 different products.

Comment: Any way you can show an example of what your dataframe looks like? It's hard to know how your data is structured just from the crosstabs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! In order to help you we'd need some more information. Please use the EDIT button under your post to add some sample data (description of the data and it's structure is essential for a proper solution) and also post the syntax you've used so far.